# ZendFramework: How to make this php code less brittle?

Tags: php, design-patterns, zend-framework2

Intern new to Zend Framework 2, been trying to make this code more adaptable:

```
class UserCohort {
    private $toString;

    function __construct($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
        if ($count < 5000) {
            $this->toString = "less_than_5k";
        } else  if ($count < 25000) {
            $this->toString = "5k_to_25k";
        } else if  ($count < 100000) {
            $this->toString = "25k_to_100k";
        } else {
            $this->toString = "greater_than_100k";
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->toString;
    }
}
```

Was trying to get enum-like functionality with range support i.e. UserCohort(4998) == UserCohort(4999) etc, depending on how you program it. I know how to do this in Java but is there a better way than my php solution above?

Didn't really find SPLENUM class to be helpful, can't think of any other design patterns to make this code less brittle, thought about factory but that seems like a lot of work for such simple functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some constants for your string and use a switch instead of if else clauses:

```
class UserCohort {
    const LESS_THEN_5K = "less_than_5k";
    const RANGE_5K_TO_25K = "5k_to_25k";
    const RANGE_25K_TO_100K = "25k_to_100k";
    const GREATER_THEN_100K = "greater_than_100k";

    private $string;

    private $count;

    function __construct($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
        switch(true){
            case $count < 5000:
                $this->string = self::LESS_THEN_5K;
                break;
            case $count < 25000:
                $this->string = self::RANGE_5K_TO_25K;
                break;
            case $count < 100000:
                $this->string = self::RANGE_25K_TO_100K;
                break;
            default:
                $this->string = self::GREATER_THEN_100K;
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->string;
    }
}
```

But I guess this is more about aesthetics then a proper alternative.
Maybe you should also consider checking the variable type `$count` that you receive as input and throw an exception if it is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the object instance like this `UserCohort(4998) == UserCohort(4999)` it will not like you expected. Because it mean you compare the `object` not the string result.
If you want to compare the string resulted from the object, you need to convert the `object` to string first. Or you can do like this

```
strval(UserCohort(4998)) == strval(UserCohort(4999));
```